# useEffect not updating dependency with queryClient.getQueryData in React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstack

I am putting  `queryClient.getQueryData` in dependency of useEffect hook to observer when data updating to cache but the useEffect never trigger update. What is the problem here?

My code below:

```
...
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
const queryKey = ['user', userId];
const userCache = queryClient.getQueryData(queryKey);
const [user, setUser] = useState(userCache || initialUserData);

// useEffect never trigger update even if userCache updated as new cache value
useEffect(() => {
    if (!userCache) return;        
    setUser((prevUser) => ({ ...prevUser, ...userCache }));
    console.log('this useEffect trigger update');
}, [userCache]);

return user;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queryClient.getQueryData` creates no *subscription* to the QueryCache - it just reads data once, whenever your component renders for another reason.

If you look at the docs, the correct way to setup a subscription and to have your component re-render whenever new data is written to the cache is via `useQuery`.